# Haskell No instance for … arising

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function that recursive counts a Taylor:

```
mcloren x = log (1+x)/(1-x)

compareWithDelta' :: (Num a, Floating a, Integral a, Ord a) => a -> a -> Bool
compareWithDelta' x acc = abs (acc - mcloren x) < 1.0e-10

mcl :: (Floating a, Integral a, Num a) => a -> a
mcl x =
 let 
  mcl' x acc y
   | compareWithDelta' x acc = acc
   | otherwise = mcl' x (2*(x^(2*y+1)/(2*y+1))) (y+1)
 in 
  mcl' x 0 0
```

But i have these error messages:

```
No instance for (Num a0) arising from a use of 'mcl'
The type variable 'a0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Num Double — Defined in 'GHC.Float'
  instance Num Float — Defined in 'GHC.Float'
  instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
    — Defined in 'GHC.Real'
  ...plus three others
In the expression: mcl 1
In an equation for 'it': it = mcl 1
```

What does it mean and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is that you're getting this "ambiguous type variable" error because your constraints `(Integral a, Floating a)` are inconsistent. There is no type that satisfies this, so when defaulting tries to find a type for `1` (in your input expression), it can't.

It gets these constraints from the power operator `(^)` taking an integral argument on the left (`2.5 ^ 2` is not valid, use `(^^)` for that), and from comparing with the float `1.0e-10`.  I'm guessing  just want to use `(^^)` instead of `(^)` and remove the `Integral` constraint.

If you're doing numerics, you will almost certainly need `fromIntegral` and `realToFrac` eventually, which are the sledgehammer conversion functions between different numeric types. Just preparing you for what's ahead.

There is one more exponential operator, `(**)`, which takes fractional numbers both on the left and right. The reason Haskell has three different exponentiation operators is fodder for another question if you are curious.

Comment: I wish GHC would allow one to specify user-programmed warnings/errors for cases like these. As in, "if after type checking/inference you find `Num (a->b)` suggest that ...".